# Openstack cloud billing software list

Tags: cloud, openstack, saas, billing

I'm searching for a billing software for cloud platforms which should do the following:

- Be able to show charts and diagrams of total cloud resources consumption (e.g. number of VCPUs, RAM, hard disk and so on) per project and user
- Be able to calculate the cost of cloud services based on the knowledge of resources consumption
- Preferrably be a web-based solution
- Be able to work uniquely with Openstack or be a universal solution supporting multiple cloud platforms

Could someone give me a less of more complete list of existing (free or paid) software **without** expressing your opinions about each position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [HostBill](http://hostbillapp.com/features/apps/openstack-technical-specs.html). It has most of the features you need.